# Java Spring Maven value from properties file

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a web service, which runs each time on different port, I have this inside my *application.properties* file: **server.port=0**, but the problem is that in my *pom.xml* I want to create schema with the following code:

```
<schemas>
         <schema>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/service/myService.wsdl</url>
         </schema>
</schemas>
```

the problem here is how can I can always this random port and use it in my *pom.xml* file

Comment: Why you need the service to run on a random port? the problem will be the same for your service consumers, they will not know the port number for your service

Comment: I need it for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random port number will be assigned in the run time, which means you can not add the port number to your POM.xml in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create profiles in maven and you add variables like your url

```xml
<profiles>  
    <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <properties>
         <port>8080</port>
      </properties>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
```

Other, You can see [Plugin for Properties in Maven](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) 
I hope to help you ;)

Comment: the thing i want is that in the properties file the web service will get some random port, and each time it gets the random port i want to use it in the maven pom.xml file